# check value exist in array with same key different value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the **true** value, but result always show **false**, how to fix this case?

```
$allow = array(
    "pdf"=>"application/pdf",
    "doc"=>"application/msword",
    "docx"=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "docx"=>"application/zip"
);

if (in_array("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",$allow)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

**In this case, I have two *.docx file but the mime type is different, how to allow both of them???**

Comment: you can't define two array elements with same key, if you used same key for two array elements then latest one override to previous

Comment: i have two file docx with different mime, how to allow both of them?

Comment: @AbuAyyub : docx1 , docx2 ??

Comment: It would be better if you create multi array for same key's e.g. , `$allow = array(
    "pdf"=>"application/pdf",
    "doc"=>"application/msword",
    "docx"=>array("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/zip")
  );`

Comment: no... but 

test.docx the mime is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
test2.docx the mime is "application/zip"

Comment: @Ranjith : In that case, he also need to check that whether key has array or not. All mimes in first level would be more feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you please try the below solution. You can make docx as one key value and put the mime as comma separated.

```
 $allow = array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/zip",
);

$allownew = array_values($allow);


if (in_array("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", $allownew))
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Very bad practice. Use ***array_values*** instead of foreach loop. Still not a recommended way. ***Use indexed array instead***

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the array contains two items with equal keys. Namely, `"application/zip"` overrides `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"`. The following is the output of `print_r($allow);`:

```
Array
(
    [pdf] => application/pdf
    [doc] => application/msword
    [docx] => application/zip
)
```

So you should specify different key for `application/zip`, e.g.:

```
$allow = array( "pdf" => "application/pdf",
  "doc" => "application/msword",
  "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  "zip" => "application/zip"
);
```

Comment: i have two file docx with different mime, how to allow both of them?

Comment: @AbuAyyub, simply use different keys for the array items

Answer (score 1):

I can see that `keys` are not important in your case. 
You can use `indexed array` instead of `multidimensional array`.

```
$allow = array("application/pdf",
               "application/msword",
               "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
               "application/zip");
```

If you really want to use multidimensional array then,

Use different keys for both mimes such as `docx1, docx2`.

```
$allow = array(
    "pdf"=>"application/pdf",
    "doc"=>"application/msword",
    "docx1"=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "docx2"=>"application/zip"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try it with a "flipped" version of the array:

```
$allow = array(
    "application/pdf"=>"pdf",
    "application/msword"=>"doc",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"=>"docx",
    "application/zip"=>"docx"
  );
```

Now, of course, you will need to search the keys of the array, not the values like

```
$k="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
If (array_key_exists($k,$array)) echo $array[$k]; // docx
```